# Setting the constructor parameters for an interface that use generics

Tags: c#, generics, dependency-injection, structuremap

As soon as i'm setting up rules for an interface that uses generics, it becomes difficult to work with. For example, this works (for a simple interface)

```
           // Imagine this interface
           public interface ISearchProvider.

           // Easy to set up with constructor parameters
            x.For<ISearchProvider>()
                .HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped()
                .Use<CatalogueSearchProvider>()
                .Ctor<bool>( "recreateDb" ).Is( false )
                .Ctor<string>("connectionString").Is( catalogConnString );
```

Compare with this:

```
// Now this interface (that use generics)
public interface IRepo<T> :  IRepo<T> where T : IEntity
```

If i want to use the same setup, I have to use "typeof" and different structuremap methods, that lack the possibility to set the constructor parameters.

```
            x.For(typeof(IRepo<>))
                .HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped()
                .Use(typeof(MyRepo<>)
                .Ctor  <-- doesn't exist!
                );
```

I can find no equivalent, is there any at all?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of injecting primitive types into constructors of your generic types, extract this information into a separate (non-generic) abstraction. This way you can prevent from even having to use the fragile `.Ctor` method calls in the first place.

For instance:

```
public class MyRepo<T> : IRepo<T> {
    private readonly IConnectionFactory connectionFactory;
    public MyRepo(IConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        this.connectionFactory = connectionFactory;
    }
}
```

With the following configuration:

```
x.For(typeof(IConnectionFactory))
    .Singleton()
    .Use(new ConnectionFactory(false, catalogConnString));

x.For(typeof(IRepo<>))
    .HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped()
    .Use(typeof(MyRepo<>));
```

Problem solved :-)

ps. Do note that the [Per Thread Lifestyle is Considered Harmful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14591422/why-is-perthreadlifetimemanager-used-in-this-example/14592419#14592419). You should use a scoped lifestyle instead.

Answer (score 0):

Its actually pretty much the same, just the method calls are named different on the non-generic calls. I double-checked and it works with open generics.

So for your example you would have:

```
x.For(typeof(IRepo<>))
            .HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped()
            .Use(typeof(MyRepo<>)
            .CtorDependency<bool>("recreateDb").Is(false)
            .CtorDependency<string>("connectionString").Is(catalogConnString);
```