# What option should use for UnitOfWork pattern by Ninject

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, ninject

I implement unit of work pattern in mvc project,

```
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    private TransactionScope _transaction;
    private readonly BodoShopEntities _db;

    public UnitOfWork()
    {
        _db = new BodoShopEntities();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (_db != null)
        {
            _db.Dispose();
        }
        System.GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    public void StartTransaction()
    {
        _transaction = new TransactionScope();
    }

    public void Commit()
    {
        _db.SaveChanges();
        _transaction.Complete();
    }

    public DbContext Db
    {
        get { return _db; }
    }
}
```

Also repository pattern,

```
public partial interface IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    T GetById(object id);
    void Insert(T entity);
    void Update(T entity);
    void Delete(T entity);
    IQueryable<T> Table { get; }
    T Single(object primaryKey);
    T SingleOrDefault(object primaryKey);
    bool Exists(object primaryKey);
    IUnitOfWork UnitOfWork { get; }
}
```

In Ninject I use InThreadScope for unit of work, Is it correct?

```
private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
{
        kernel.Bind(typeof(IUnitOfWork)).To(typeof(UnitOfWork)).InThreadScope();
}
```

Comment: Using the InThreadScope inside an ASP.NET application is a very bad idea: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14591422/why-is-perthreadlifetimemanager-used-in-this-example

Comment: You might also find this Q/A informative: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10585478/one-dbcontext-per-web-request-why

Answer (score 1):

For web application use `InRequestScope()`. Do not forget to register `OnePerRequestModule` as well, so the `UnitOfWork`/db context will be disposed at the end of the request.

---

`InRequestScope()` extension is currently located at [Ninject.Web.Common](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Web.Common/wiki/InRequestScope)