# What is the equivalent of HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped in structure map 3?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, structuremap, structuremap3

With structuremap 2.6.4.1 my container is configured like this:

```
existingContainer.Configure(expression =>
{
    expression.For<IDocumentSession>()                    
        .HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped()
        .Use(container =>
        {
            var store = container.GetInstance<IDocumentStore>();                        
            return store.OpenSession();
         });
}
```

`HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped` does not exist in structure map 3 so my question is, what is the equivalent configuration in structuremap 3?

Comment: You should be very careful with Per Thread lifestyles. Take a look at this Q/A: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14591422/why-is-perthreadlifetimemanager-used-in-this-example.

Comment: @Steven that's an inaccurate assessment of structuremap it will only fallback to a thread lifetime if there is no context available like inside a unit/integration test. `HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped`  is one of the very best features of structuremap

Comment: @ChrisMarisic: I disagree with you. Even in a unit test it is bad, because this will prevent tests from running in isolation. But even if you use per-thread lifestyle in your unit tests, this is still not a good reason to use this `HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped` in your production configuration, because in case of the absence of a HTTP context, an object will live for the duration of the application; hardly ever a good idea.

Comment: We're going to just disagree then. `HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped` is an ultimate reason to use StructureMap and i use it in every project i use StructureMap

Answer (score 27, accepted):

As of StructureMap 3, anything `HttpContext` related lives within a separate Nuget package called `StructureMap.Web` which can be [found here](http://www.nuget.org/packages/structuremap.web/).

The reason for this is StructureMap 3 is now PLC (Portalble Class Library) compliant, so splitting web-related lifecycles into its own package makes sense.

Comment: I think you should answer his question.  I don't see any hybrid approach inside StructureMap.Web.

Comment: It's in there, look inside of [CreatePluginFamilyExpressionExtensions.cs](https://github.com/structuremap/structuremap/blob/master/src/StructureMap.Web/CreatePluginFamilyExpressionExtensions.cs)

Answer (score 2):

It is there, says here http://jeremydmiller.com/2014/03/31/structuremap-3-0-is-live/ that is now a Structuremap.Web nuget to add to your project for it to work.