# How to invoke HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped in StructureMap 3

Tags: structuremap, structuremap3

I am trying to move from Structuremap 2.6.4.1 to 3.1.4.143 but am unable to figure out how to handle HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped. None of the SO Q/A I can find seems to work for me...

I have the following code:

```
using StructureMap;
using StructureMap.Web;

ObjectFactory.Configure( x =>
{
    x.For<IRepository<Person>>()
        .HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped() // Need the repo to survive for the duration of the thread!
        .Use<Repository_Stub<Person>>()
        .Ctor<IEnumerable<IEntity>>( "seed" ).Is( persons );
} );
```

that gives me this error:

```
'StructureMap.Configuration.DSL.Expressions.CreatePluginFamilyExpression<IRepository<Person>>' 
does not contain a definition for 'HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped' and no extension method
'HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped' accepting a first argument of type
StructureMap.Configuration.DSL.Expressions.CreatePluginFamilyExpression<IRepository<Person>>'
could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Is there a new way to invoke HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped?

Thansk in advance!

Answer (score 5):

`HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped` has been moved into a separate nuget package called `Structuremap.Web`.

It can be installed by running `Install-Package structuremap.web` in your Nuget Package Console. 
[See this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23040851/what-is-the-equivalent-of-hybridhttporthreadlocalscoped-in-structure-map-3/23110166#23110166) for more information.