# Which Lifecycle Replaces the old HybridLifecycle?

Tags: structuremap, structuremap3

Which Structuremap v3 `Lifecycle` is recommended to replace the old `HybridLifecycle`? Specifically for a `UnitOfWork` in a web app environment?

Comment: Please be careful in using any lifestyle that has thread-afinity, such as `ThreadLocalScoped` or `HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped` as [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14591422/why-is-perthreadlifetimemanager-used-in-this-example).

Comment: Currently using HttpContextLifecycle for my UOW. I assume that is preferred?

Comment: HttpContext should not pose any trouble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add reference to **StructureMap.Web** Assembly.

**Import** these namespaces(they contain extension methods):

```
Imports StructureMap.Web
Imports StructureMap.Web.Pipeline
```

then you can use:

```
HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped
```

Comment: Didn't realize there was a separate library for the `Web` stuff. Thanks!