# Threads, thread pool & Unity's ThreadScope

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, unity-container

I have a question about threads, the thread pool for ASP.net and Unity's Thread Scope object scope.  From what I understand, each request for an ASP.net site gets its own thread & when the request is finished the thread goes back to the thread pool.  Is that correct?

If that is true then how does that affect the use of Thread Scope in Unity?  If we use that and the thread ends up back in the thread pool, does the Unity object just stick around?  Does the thread do any garbage collection on it's variables when its sent to the pool?  It must do something like since it handles different requests.

I guess my question is, when exactly are threads garbage collected?

[Unity Object Scope Definitions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660872(v=pandp.20).aspx)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is PerThreadLifetimeManager used in this example?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14591422/why-is-perthreadlifetimemanager-used-in-this-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that a .NET `Thread` object is not the same as the thread that it represents. The latter is an operating system concept and even though .NET threads have been abstracted away from Windows threads you can assume that a .NET thread gets its ability to execute code from a Windows thread unless you are in an exotic environment.

> I guess my question is, when exactly are threads garbage collected?

`Thread` objects can only be garbage collected when the associated thread has terminated and the `Thread` is no longer reachable from any GC roots. `Thread` objects in the .NET thread pool does not get garbage collected as long as they are in the thread pool.

If you use `PerThreadLifetimeManager` in Unity then there will be a separate instance for each thread. Each call to `Resolve` from the same thread will return the same instance but calls to `Resolve` from different threads will return different instances.

Note that `PerThreadLifetimeManager` will not dispose any instances when the associated thread terminates.

If you use async and await in your ASP.NET code a single request may be processed by multiple threads.

`PerThreadLifetimeManager` is built on top of thread local storage and can be used to improve performance in multithreaded code. However, thread local storage is often confusing and in my opinion should not be used unless it is really necessary.

Comment: thanks 1 more question.  1) If I use TransientLifetimeManager I see that the container does not have a reference to the instance.  But is the instance a normal object?  Meaning will the instance that is resolved GC be eligible when it goes out of scope?  Just checking to be sure I'm not creating a memory leak

Comment: @MrSmith: I have not actually checked this but I would expect that `PerThreadLifetimeManager` does not introduce any memory leaks. I assume that it uses thread local storage and an instance created using that lifetime manager will then be eligble for garbage collection after the associated thread has terminated.