# Reason to use PerThreadLifetimemanager vs Transientlifetimemanager

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, dependency-injection, unity-container

I use DI in constructors.
BaseShoppingCart is a service in which I set ShoppingCartId (used for cart items).
here is the constructor:

```
public BaseShoppingCart( HttpContextBase context, IRepository<TCart> cart  ,IProductService productservice)
{  
    _context = context;
    _cart = cart;
     _productService = productservice;
    ShoppingCartId = _context.Request.IsAuthenticated ? _context.User.Identity.Name : getSessionCartId();
}
```

- If I set Transientlifetimemanager (by default) in DI container (Unity) no bugs are revealed.
- If I set PerThreadLifetimeManager any user may get  **cart of another user**!  As I read from this article [Why is PerThreadLifetimeManager used in this example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14591422/why-is-perthreadlifetimemanager-used-in-this-example) - thread is longer than request so second call of ShoppingCartController is this case may not invoke ctor of BaseShoppingCart. Instead existing BaseShoppingCart object (object of another user) is returned from container.

I need your opinions:

1. Do I understand this problem correcltly?
2. In which cases PerThreadLifetimemanager is useful insted of Transientlifetimemanager?

Thanks!

Comment: A cart is user-specific, so it doesn't make sense to use per-thread lifetime in that case. But there can be other services that are not user-specific ; for instance, if all users have access to the same products, the IProductService can be per-thread.

Comment: Thanks! Should DBContext be Per-thread ?

Comment: Probably not; typically the DBContext is per-request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To isolate users (requests) create new child container per request and resolve services from child one. So, you can register your services with `HierarchicalLifetimeManager` and you'll get new instance for each user (request).

[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660872(v=pandp.20).aspx) are good examples.

And I don't recommend to use PerThreadLifetimeManager if you don't know, what you actualy do.

Comment: Приятно видеть своих :) Не совсем понял, что даст HierarchicalLifetimeManager в сравнении с Transientlifetimemanager

Comment: @ВладимирЛапенков Transientlifetimemanager дает тебе всегда новый инстанс, что не верно, в случае когда тебе, например, нужно делить DbContext на все сервисы в рамках одного вызова (или UnitOfWork). Т.е. тут все сервисы могут быть созданы по-дефолту, а вот UnitOfWork у них должен быть один. При этом, у разных пользователей (запросов, т.к. у тебя MVC) должен быть разный тот самый UnitOfWork. Для этого он и регистрируется с HierarchicalLifetimeManager и резолвится из дочернего контейнера. Т.е. изоляция между пользователями происходит на уровне контейнеров.

Comment: @ВладимирЛапенков вот хорошая ссылка на эту тему https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660872(v=pandp.20).aspx

Comment: HierarchicalLifetimeManager делает единственный сервис в рамках requestа для каждого контроллера, это мне и нужно. То есть вызовов конструктора контроллера -5 а экземпляр - один. Я не использую UnitOfWork. Внедряю сами сервисы в контроллер по образу nopCommerse. Спасибо за инфу!

Comment: @ВладимирЛапенков если мой ответ тебе помог, не мог бы ты его отметить?