# C# Thread singletons

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, singleton

I'm designing a C# library that's used both in a web environment and in a stand-alone multi-threaded application. I need thread singletons for several ephemeral resources (database connection, cluster mutex locking server connection, etc).

When the code runs in the web environment I'm using [`HttpContext.Current`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.current%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to store several types of thread singleton instances in a container. Is there a similarly easy way to accomplish this when the code is running in a stand-alone application, or do I have to write my own?

Comment: Have look at `ThreadStaticAttribute`https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threadstaticattribute(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Or `ThreadLocal<T>`.

Comment: Even in a stand-alone application, I think that storing db connections per thread is not a good approach. Connections should typically have a very short lifespan and theads tend to live for a very long period of time. Also take a look at [this related q/a](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14592419/264697).

Comment: @Steven that's a legitimate point, thank you. HttpContext should be safe though, because it's provisioned specifically for that purpose. I do still need a uniform solution for the whole thing, so it looks like I'll probably have to roll my own, making sure to clean it up explicitly when threads die. Had hoped to avoid this, but it's better to find out sooner rather than later.

Comment: @Gutza: I think the application developer should be able to define some sort of scope around some request/operation. This should allow that developer to create/dispose the resources around the scope's boundaries.

Comment: @Steven, it's a bit late for us to consider scoping in the literal sense (RAII style), because we already have a lot of code that expects to use those resources singleton style (just grab it an use it). I'll have to work around that, and this is the best solution I have right now. If things turn sour, we could re-initialize the entire container. Having said that, I still find the idea of frequent DB reconnects unappealing, on performance grounds (and general wastefulness). I understand the safety concerns, but I'd very much like to find a way to accommodate both safety and efficiency.

Comment: You are aware that .NET uses connection pooling to reuse connections, don't' you? It's very unlikely that you'll see performance problems by closing connections quickly.

Comment: Fair enough, that's true for DB connections, but we're storing several other types of resources and connections (e.g. ZooKeeper) which probably aren't as well optimized.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to let your library depend upon an interface that abstracts the way those resources are stored. This allows the application to create an implementation and decide this for itself, or you can supply a few default implementations out-of-the-box in your library, where an application programmer can choose from.

Comment: For a generic library this is what I'd do. But this particular library is designed specifically for a single in-house project, so we're free to impose a given uniform approach. Strangely enough, I had forgotten about the ThreadStatic attribute, so I'll be using Dmitry's solution – it's even easier than HttpContext.Current...