# Constructor with Dependencies

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject, ninject-2

What I want is for Ninject to resolve this type of situation:

```
Class1(IClass2 a, IClass3, b, IClass c, IClass d) : IClass1

Class2() : IClass2

Class3(IClass2 a) : IClass3
```

So just to explain `Class1` has a dependency on `IClass2`, which is injected in first, the remaining parameters are all of type `IClass3` which itself has a dependency on `IClass2`.  What I need is a way to get a new instance of `Class1` and make sure that the **same instance** of `IClass2` is used when Ninject resolves the dependencies for the instances of type `IClass3`.

Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ninject [Object Scopes](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Object-Scopes).
**Some examples:**

- `InSingletonScope()` will create one instance of the object
  for the entire app:

  ```
  Bind<IClass2>().To<Class2>().InSingletonScope();
  ```
- `InThreadScope()`will create one instance of the object for every thread:

  ```
  Bind<IClass2>().To<Class2>().InThreadScope();
  ```

You can find more other scopes in the link above.

Comment: That probably works well for what I need.  I don't think it will matter too much if the `Class2` instance is shared between 2 instances of `Class1` in the same thread.  Thanks!

Comment: Please don't use the `InThreadScope`. The [per thread lifestyle is very bad](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14592419/264697). Use `InScope` or `InRequestScope` instead.