# Intercepting on an Interface

Tags: c#, ninject, interceptor, convention, ninject-interception

I am trying to make something like an `IAuditable` interface, which acts as a marker for Ninject to intercept calls to.

Suppose I have the following:

```
public interface IAuditable
{

}

public interface IProcessor
{
    void Process(object o);
}

public class Processor : IProcessor, IAuditable
{
    public void Process(object o)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Processor called with argument " + o.ToString());
    }
}
```

With this setup:

```
NinjectSettings settings = new NinjectSettings() { LoadExtensions = true };
IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel(settings);
kernel.Bind<IAuditAggregator>().To<AuditAggregator>().InThreadScope();
kernel.Bind<IAuditInterceptor>().To<AuditInterceptor>();

kernel.Bind(x =>
            x.FromThisAssembly()
            .SelectAllClasses()
            .InheritedFrom<IAuditable>()
            .BindToDefaultInterfaces() //I suspect I need something else here
            .Configure(c => c.Intercept().With<IAuditInterceptor>()));
kernel.Bind<IProcessor>().To<Processor>();
```

Whenever I try to `kernel.Get<IProcessor>();` I get an exception telling me there are multiple bindings available.

If I remove `kernel.Bind<IProcessor>().To<Processor>()` then it works as expected, but it is possible that you can have an `IProcessor` that does not implement `IAuditable`.

Am I on the right track?

Edit: As suggested I tried using an attribute instead:

```
public class AuditableAttribute : Attribute
{

}
[Auditable]
public class Processor : IProcessor
{

    public void Process(object o)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Processor called with argument " + o.ToString());
    }
}
//in setup:
kernel.Bind(x =>
            x.FromThisAssembly()
            .SelectAllClasses()
            .WithAttribute<AuditableAttribute>()
            .BindDefaultInterface()
            .Configure(c => c.Intercept().With<IAuditInterceptor>()));
```

This results in the same duplicate binding issue as with using an interface instead.

Comment: I think in that case the use of an [Auditable] attribute is better than using a marker-interface.

Comment: I suppose you can write a conditional statement inside the `Configure` lambda that calls `Intercept()` only when the type implements the interface (or is marked with the attribute).

Comment: Using an attribute results in the same outcome, a duplicate binding is created.

Comment: Btw, about the use of `InThreadScope`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14592419/264697

Comment: I am not sure I understand what your problem is. You are using `SelectAllClasses` which effectively picks up `Processor` because of the marker interface or the attribute. You then "manually" add another binding at the bottom so of course it's going to complain.

Comment: Yes, I don't know how to avoid that. Basically I need to bind everything that does have the interface/attribute separately from those that don't.

Comment: But your code already works that way, I think. By adding your manual binding at the bottom, you are mapping a class that was already bound because it implements the interface.

Comment: The single line "manual" binding is there to demonstrate the problem in a simple application. In reality I will be using `kernel.Bind(x => x.FromThisAssembly().SelectAllClasses().InheritedFrom<IProcessor>().BindDefaultInterface().Configure(c => c.InSingletonScope()));`. That will handle all "normal" cases where I don't want things to be audited, but will not install the interceptor for cases where I do.

Comment: This sounds like a job for @ChrisShain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to write one convention binding for types implementing IAuditable and one for types not implementing.

```
        kernel.Bind(x =>
            x.FromThisAssembly()
                .SelectAllClasses()
                .InheritedFrom<IAuditable>()
                .BindDefaultInterfaces()
                .Configure(c => c.Intercept().With<IAuditInterceptor>()));

        kernel.Bind(x =>
            x.FromThisAssembly()
                .SelectAllClasses()
                .InheritedFrom<IProcessor>()
                .Where(t => !typeof(IAuditable).IsAssignableFrom(t))
                .BindDefaultInterfaces());
```