# How can I register a DbContext class in an IoC container?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, asp.net-mvc-5, unity-container

I have a project written using c# on the top of ASP.NET MVC 5 framework. I setup an `IoC` container using [Unity.Mvc](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Unity.Mvc/).

During the registration process I registered my `UnitOfWork` and `DbContext` using the `HierarchicalLifetimeManager`

But it seems to me that `Unity` is registering these object into the memory of the server and any request the come from any users, gets the same instance. In fact, when I altered by database using SQL Server Management Studio and refreshed my page, I did not see the updated data on the screen. Obviously this isn't the behavior I would want in an asp.net mvc 5 app.

Then I thought about changing the life-time-manager to `PerThreadLifetimeManager`, but according [to this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14591422/why-is-perthreadlifetimemanager-used-in-this-example/14592419) It is a bad idea.

Then I tried to use `PerRequestLifetimeManager`, but when I log a user in I get this following error

> The `PerRequestLifetimeManager` can only be used in the context of an
>   HTTP request.Possible causes for this error are using the lifetime
>   manager on a non-ASP.NET application, or using it in a thread that is
>   not associated with the appropriate synchronization context.

What is the right way to Register the `UnitOfWork` and `DbContext` classes in a project?

Comment: `PerRequestLifetimeManager` would appear to be the correct life time scope to define for a MVC project. Can you post your code that includes this? please include all relevant `Startup` / `Global.asax` code please.

Comment: Vote suggested because no more information has been provided to make this answerable.