# Does thread scope in ninject creates new dbcontext on every thread call

Tags: multithreading, entity-framework, scope, ninject

I have configured ninject in wep api as below. I have created two kernel objects, one in request scope and another in thread scope:

```
var requestKernel = new StandardKernel();
requestKernel.Bind<IGlobalDbContext>().ToConstructor(ctx => new GlobalDbContext(Configuration.GlobalDbContext)).InRequestScope();

var threadKernel = new StandardKernel();
RegisterServices(threadKernel);
threadKernel.Bind<IGlobalDbContext>().ToConstructor(ctx => new GlobalDbContext(Configuration.GlobalDbContext)).InThreadScope();
new Kernel(threadKernel);
```

Here new Kernel is a class for creating thread scope `DBContext`:

```
public class Kernel
{
    private static StandardKernel _kernel = null;

    public Kernel(StandardKernel kernel)
    {
        if (_kernel == null)
        {
            _kernel = kernel;
        }
    }

    public static IKernel GetKernel
    {
        get
        {
            return _kernel;
        }
    }
}
```

Now I have created two tasks in below action methods:

```
[HttpPost]
public void RunThreadrequest()
{
    ThreadFactory threadFactory = new ThreadFactory();
    DateTime fromDate = Convert.ToDateTime("2018-05-01");
    DateTime toDate = Convert.ToDateTime("2018-05-31");
    List<int> orders = _orderManager.All().Where(o => o.IsActive && (o.DeliveryDate >= fromDate && o.DeliveryDate <= toDate)).Select(o => (int)o.Id).ToList();
    int length = 2;
    int i = 0;
    int startIndex = 0;
    int endIndex = orders[0] - 1;
    do
    {
        startIndex = endIndex + 1;
        endIndex = startIndex + 5;
        OrderIndex ordIndexObj = new OrderIndex { StartIndex = startIndex, EndIndex = endIndex };
        threadFactory.CreateThread((ordIndex) =>
        {
            ParameterConfigurationController controller =  (ParameterConfigurationController)(Kernel.GetKernel.GetService(typeof(ParameterConfigurationController)));
            controller.UpdateOrders(((OrderIndex)ordIndex).StartIndex, ((OrderIndex)ordIndex).EndIndex);
        }, ordIndexObj);
        i++;
    } while (i < length);
    threadFactory.Run();
}

public struct OrderIndex
{
    public int StartIndex { get; set; }
    public int EndIndex { get; set; }
    public int ThreadId { get; set; }
    public int Index { get; set; }
}
```

The above code will create two thread and call the method `UpdateOrders`:

```
public void UpdateOrders(int startIndex, int lastIndex)
{
    var orders = _orderManager.All().Where(o => o.Id >= startIndex && o.Id <= lastIndex).ToList();
    foreach (Order order in orders)
    {
        order.StatusId = 11;
    }      
    _orderManager.SaveChanges();
}
```

Thread code:

```
class ThreadFactory
{
    private List<Task> threads = new List<Task>();
    private CancellationTokenSource source = new CancellationTokenSource();
    private CancellationToken token;
    public ThreadFactory()
    {
        token = source.Token;
    }

    public void CreateThread(Action<object> action, OrderIndex ordObj)
    {
        if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
            token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew(action, ordObj, token);
        threads.Add(task);
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        Task.WaitAll(this.threads.ToArray());
    }
}
```

What I observed is: when `SaveChanges` is called in one thread and I refresh the database no records are effected with status 11. When second thread done its execution then the records gets effected.

My question is,

1) does `InThreadScope()` creates one `dbcontext` per thread or multiple `dbcontext`?

2) Is there any transaction maintained by `Task.WaitAll` so that all the threads execution will be committed at once

Please suggest, if I am missing anything.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14591422/why-is-perthreadlifetimemanager-used-in-this-example/14592419#14592419

Comment: Regardless of your DI configuration, your threads appear to be using a single instance of your DbContext, _orderManager.

Comment: I have modified my configuration and tried to create new StandardKernel object in each thread. Then it is working fine, even if I give InRequestScope to newly created kernel. My question is, did I configured InThreadScope correctly or am I using InThreadScope for correct purpose?