# How to use multi threading with entity framework in web api 2

Tags: multithreading, entity-framework, ninject

We are going to create a product from our existing application. Our existing application is using Entity framework 6, Web API 2, ninject. So instead of creating a new design and using a new technologies, we are using same technologies i.e,Entity framework 6, Web API 2, ninject. There will be heavy database operations. We are able to divide the complete operations to small tasks. So we decided to use multi threading. My question is.

1) How to configure ninject to create a new dbcontext on every thread call?

2) Once the thread done its operations, the database changes should effect immediately irrespective of remaining threads done their operations or not.

3) Once each thread operations are done, the thread should be disposed along with its dbcontext.

4) Will there be any side effects on using multi threading in entity framwork.

A coding examples will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> 1) How to configure ninject to create a new dbcontext on every thread call?

Use [Tasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-based-asynchronous-programming).  Inside each Task create a new DbContext in a `using` block.  I guess in ninject that means a [Transient](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Object-Scopes) scope.

> 2) Once the thread done its operations, the database changes should effect immediately irrespective of remaining threads done their operations or not.

Using a separate DbContext in each Task should do that.

> 4) Will there be any side effects on using multi threading in entity framework.

You may experience locking waits, resource exhaustion, or deadlocking in your database.

> 3) Once each thread operations are done, the thread should be disposed along with its dbcontext.

With Tasks you don't have explicitly manage the Threads.

> A coding examples will be greatly appreciated.

It's not clear exactly why you want to use parallelism in the client.  If you could explain that a bit, including details about your databsae, there might be relevant coding examples.  Or it may become clear that multi threading at the client is just not helpful.

Comment: I have created a StandardKernel ninject object and made it as InThreadScope(). I have created multiple tasks and in each task, I have created controller object with constructor injection from above created kernel object like {var obj=kernel.GetService(typeof(SomeController);  Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew(obj.SomeMethod()); tasks.Add(task); } and finally calling Task.WaitAll(tasks). But I have observed that database changes are getting effected when all tasks are done. Is there anything wrong.

Comment: My application is something like we are working for gasoline supply client. Client wants to know what whether they have lifted gasoline from lowest price supply point or not. For that we have to get monthly invoices from their database and create orders for those invoices and run our optimizer for those orders. There will be like 15 to 20 thousand orders per month. Client will select various suppliers from UI and run the optimizer. So the response should be fast. So we are going with threading.

Comment: Hard to tell anything from the comments.  You might build a short, standalone example program and post that. But you should probably scope the DbContext inside each task.

Comment: Please follow the below link. I have created an example and explained how I have created kernel object and called inside tasks.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51880046/does-thread-scope-in-ninject-creates-new-dbcontext-on-every-thread-call